# $smarty->escape_html = true not working

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I am trying to escape the output in my Smarty templates. If I do this:

```
{$library[all].text|escape:"html"}
```

In the template it works fine but if I do this in the PHP:

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
...
$smarty->escape_html = TRUE;
```

and have this in the template:

```
{$library[all].text}
```

The output doesn't get escaped.

I make sure I delete the complied templates from templates_c before testing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem

Comment: No in the end I had to go through all my templates adding |escape:"html". I am guessing that it is a bug in Smarty.

Comment: Hum ok.. Thanks for your reply after 1.5 years !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation of this option:

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl

Especially the note:

> This is a compile time option. If you change the setting you must make
>   sure that the templates get recompiled.

Comment: Wouldn't deleting all the templates in templates_c achieve that?